# rmtree: Find and delete svn directory recursively

Tags: perl

I tried deleting the `.svn` directory recursively through :

```
system("rm -rf `find . -type d -name .svn`");
```

But, I want to do the same using Perl function `rmtree` (from `File::Path`). How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );
use File::Path       qw( rmtree );

rmtree([
    File::Find::Rule
     ->directory
      ->name('.svn')
       ->prune
        ->in('.')
]);
```

Your version didn't prune, but it should have.

Comment: I get the following error message: Can't locate method File::Find::Rule::dir

Comment: Is there another way to do the same?

Comment: The execution just stops as soon as it hits the rmtree line for me. Please help

Comment: It could take a while to scan your disk and do the deletions.